# Why Driver code is executing first?

Tags: linux-device-driver

I am calling a driver function from application by using an ioctl(). By using logs i found that my kernel code is executing first. for example,

In my application

printf("Calling Driver");
ioctl();

In my driver

printk("Driver called");

When i execute my code, first it is printing "Driver called" and then  "Calling Driver" 
I there any reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `stdout` stream is buffered, and the datas are only displayed after a newline (or the end of execution). In this case, the display is done after the `ioctl` call.

Your can force the display using `fflush` after your `printf` call.

```
printf("Calling Driver");
fflush(stdout);
ioctl();
```

For more details, you can read [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1716296/1109005).